# Android Espresso can't type in TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL?

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I have a TextInputEditText view in my android application, and I am setting it up programmatically (via Anko and Kotlin) like this:

```
            textInputEditText {
                id = R.id.text_input_id
                inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL
                hint = resources.getText(R.string.text_hint)
            }
```

Then in an Espresso test I call this line:

```
onView(withId(R.id.text_input_id)).perform(typeText(textToType))
```

Which fails with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
((is displayed on the screen to the user) and (supports input methods or is assignable from class: class android.widget.SearchView))
Target view: "TextInputEditText{id=2131623954, res-name=text_input_id, visibility=VISIBLE, width=862, height=118, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

I've discovered that if I switch it from this:

```
/**
 * Default variation of {@link #TYPE_CLASS_TEXT}: plain old normal text.
 */
public static final int TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL = 0x00000000;
```

To this:

```
/**
 * Variation of {@link #TYPE_CLASS_TEXT}: entering a password, which should
 * be visible to the user.
 */
public static final int TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD = 0x00000090;
```

It suddenly magically works! But that doesn't make much sense. The normal text sounds like the right one to use until Espresso blows up in my face. Is this a bug with Espresso, or something I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is happening inside the `typeText` call. See the list of constraints in `TypeTextAction.getConstraints()`. The logic is essentially:

```
isDisplayed() &&
hasFocus() &&
( supportsInputMethods() || isAssignableFrom(SearchView.class) )
```

My first guess is that it's not passing the `supportsInputMethods()` constraint. You can put a break point inside `ViewMatchers.supportsInputMethods() -> matchesSafely()` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` instead of `EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL` to make Espresso work.

`TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL` is causing `supportsInputMethods()` ViewMatcher (that `typeText()` is using internally) to fail for some reason.

`TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` will give similar input type as `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL`.